# Remote Backup System needed

Tags: windows, backup, networking

I work for a large organization that is not in the IT industry. As such, we have a lot of users that aren't very computer savvy. They know enough about computers to do their jobs, but not much more.

We've been hit with ransomware several times over the last 6 months. Luckily while we've lost some data we haven't lost anything critical and what we have lost has been able to be recreated.

What we'd like to do is to back up key computers (especially executive staff) remotely. I'm looking for commercial software that does the following:

- Works with Windows 7, XP, Server 2010.
- Allows the ability to store backups on our servers (Organization policy forbids us from storing certain types of data on "the cloud")
- Does not require the computer being backed up to be mapped to a drive (the ransomware also encrypts files on mapped drives).
- As it's being done remotely, does not slow the user down.
  Also as it's being done remotely, can connect to the computer after it's been shut down and restarted.
- Can be scheduled to be run during a specified timeframe.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Something worth considering is backing up your backups periodically, and have that process *write only*

Comment: Which of these are negotiable? The remote bit is tricky. I have native apps that are pretty low impact and dosen't really slow the system

Comment: The remote part is first and foremost.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you take a look at [CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/products/).  While I don't use it in a large organization, I do use it "remotely" in that the server runs on an Ubuntu box and backs up several PCs running Windows 7.  All machines are on the same network.  I do not store backups in the "cloud".  They are kept on the server.

CrashPlan lists the following features that should be of interest to you.

- Back up any device, anywhere
- Automatic and silent
- Unlimited files and versions
- Identity management with two-factor authentication

In addition, you can schedule the backups for each machine you want to protect.

Comment: Something worth adding is crashplan has a 'backup to a friend' option which would probably meet many of the OP's needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TimeDicer](http://www.timedicer.co.uk). It is a batch program utilizing rdiff-backup which uses librsync, backs up only the file differences (perhaps, default setting). It works with many Windows OSs, backs up to a server running linux. Once configured, you get a file that you can set to run automatically every day or so f.e. in windows task scheduler.

Comment: I'll check TimeDicer out, but we don't have any Linux machines (besides one test machine and one Raspberry Pi being evaluated).